# Windows Phone 7 - quick scroll list control?

Tags: silverlight, list, listview, windows-phone-7

On Android ListView control we can use FastScroll feature (handle on the right side of screen). On iPhone list control can show alphabetical grid for fast scrolling (see screenshots below).

Do we have something similar for Windows Phone 7? I have a list with ~500-2000 entries sorted alphabetically and I'd like to make it more usable - also with possibility to programatically scroll to selected row.

I found Jump List Control ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/WindowsPhone7JumpLIst.aspx)) - is there anything else, maybe more intuitional to use?

[image: Android]

[image: iPhone]

Answer (score 8):

In Windows Phone, you can use the `LongListSelector` control, which is part of the official [Silverlight Toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). There's a good couple of articles on [WindowsPhoneGeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api) that show you to use it.